# Can Reaper be use for beat creation like that in FL studio?

Tags: software

I used FL studio for easy beat creation. See here:
http://www.metacafe.com/watch/1376781/fl_studio_tutorial_how_to_make_a_simple_beat_in_fl_studio/

Now i heard about Reaper which is awesome and low-cost:
http://www.reaper.fm

I downloaded test and manual but couldn't find anything to make beats as easy as on fl studio.
Isn't this featured in reaper?

which "cheap but good" software (under 100$) features the onscreen beat creation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few options for you.

http://tutorialsforreaper.com/2010/08/03/drums-as-click-gtg-synth-drums-midi-drums-as-click-basic-beat-creation/

This is free and you can create beats to the depth of your beat knowledge with this and the built in tools that come with reaper.

Reaper is fairly robust in the midi department so you could use just about any VST/DXI instrument you wanted to play the beats from midi.

As far as software for under a 100 why not stick with what you know http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/image-line-fl-studio-10-fruity-loops/h74334000000000.

You can record from FL studio into reaper.
http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/6891224